# Self made port scanner not working with JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

So I have created a port scanner in Java.

While using Swing, everything works smoothly with 0 errors.

I however tried to convert my app to a JavaFX style of GUI, and nothing works when I press the buttons (Even though I have set the method ID's in the GUI builder).

[image]

What seems to be my problem?

My code:

```
package networkTools.gui;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class PortScannerController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TextField hostName;
    @FXML
    TextField fromPort;
    @FXML
    TextArea log;
    @FXML
    Button scan;
    @FXML
    Button reset;
    @FXML
    Label label;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        hostName.requestFocus();
    }

    public void initFocus() {
        hostName.requestFocus();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onScan() {
        int fp;
        String h;
        Socket s;
        if (hostName.getText().equals("")) {
            log.setText("Fill everything correct.");
            return;
        } else if (fromPort.getText().equals("")) {
            log.setText("Fill everything correct..");
            return;
        } else if (!fromPort.getText().matches("[0-9]*")) {
            log.setText("Give a number for a port ");
            return;
        }
        // scan.disable(false);
        reset.setText("Stop");
        log.setText("");
        log.clear();
        label.setText("");
        h = hostName.getText();
        fp = Integer.parseInt(fromPort.getText());

        label.setText("Port " + fp + " being tested (max +- 15 sec.)");

        try {
            s = new Socket(h, fp);
            log.appendText("Poort " + fp + " is open.\n");
            log.clear();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception er) {
            log.appendText("Poort " + fp + " is closed");
        }

        // scan.setEnabled(true);
        reset.setText("Reset");
        label.setText("Press scan to start.");

    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" stylesheets="@style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="networkTools.gui.PortScannerController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Label id="title" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="Port Scanner" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <GridPane>
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="131.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="407.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="269.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Host Name">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Port" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="fromPort" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <ToggleButton id="commandbutton" fx:id="onScan" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Scan" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton id="commandbutton" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Reset" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </ToggleButton>
            <TextField fx:id="hostName" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <TextArea id="textpane" fx:id="log" editable="false" prefHeight="148.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </TextArea>
      <StackPane prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="380.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Press Scan to start" textFill="#1815c9">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Can you post the FXML?

Answer (score 2):

There is nowhere that you associate the handler with the button. You need an `onAction="#onScan"` in the FXML for the "Scan" button:

```xml
<ToggleButton id="commandbutton" onAction="#onScan" fx:id="onScan" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Scan" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
```

There are several other things that look incorrect in your FXML:

1. You have several elements with the same CSS id (`"commandButton"` for example); you should use a `styleClass` instead of an `id` if you want to share style among several components.
2. You declare an `fx:id="onScan"` for the button above, but there is no field in your controller called `onScan`.
3. It's not really clear why you are using a `ToggleButton` instead of a regular `Button` for what appears to be an action. `ToggleButton`s are generally intended for toggling between two different states, not issuing a command/action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer James_D. I'm having problems applying your answer but i'll try my best to get it working. It is my first approach in using JavaFX for GUI, hence the mistakes I did. Would the ToggleButton however won't be a better thing in this tool? Since I need to have the possibility to stop/reset/start a scan? Thanks